# getting a random choice from a function in js

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to write a function to get a random value in the rock,paper,scissor game in the computer  choice but my code is returning undefined when I'm calling the function.What might be the problem in my code.

[image: this is my code please click to see what i tried to do]

Comment: `this is my code` - no, that's a picture of your code, put the code in the question - P.S. your code doesn't return anything from that function, it changes a global variable, so, console.log of the function result won't show jack

Comment: Your function has no `return` statement so implicitly returns `undefined`. You would need to call it then log `computer` to get the result

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)